# Can I "lock" the scroll bar when I switch between saves (commits) in PyCharm local history view?

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm Community Edition, when I am viewing the changes in local history I want to see the changes between different saves (commits) immediately pop out as I select different commits, in addition to the highlighted changes between that commit and current revision. This can be done if the vertical view position stays where it is, at least approximately. However, the view jumps and resets (to apparently where there the most changes are?) every time I select a new commit. How can I disable this jumping behavior?

Of course I can close the history view, highlight part of a text, and "Show Hisotory for Selection", but that would be tedious for every change I want to track.

Comment: This is not a python question

Comment: @itprorh66, right, sorry. Just copied tags from another IDE question.